# Operational Process Specifications chart in r

Tags: r

Is there any package to create opspecs(Operational Process Specifications)chart in r for six sigma analysis?

OperationalProcessSpecifications Chart
[image: OperationalProcessSpecifications Chart screenshot]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any data that we could work with to help you find a solution? If you are looking for software recommendations, I'm afraid that is off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: @AllanCameron which StackExchange site do you suggest then?